# jquery function unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to write a reusable function in jquery for a style guide I'm creating.  The goal of the function is to hide/show a number of divs based on the value of a range slider.

The html code looks like this

```
<div class="primary-colors">
    <h3>Primary Colors</h3>
    <div class="primary-range-container">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value ="5" class="primary-slider"><span class="value">0</span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="color-container">
        <div class="color primary-color-1"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-2"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-3"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-4"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-5"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-6"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-7"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-8"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-9"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-10"></div>
        <div class="color primary-color-11"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript code looks like this

```
var primarySlider = $(".primary-slider");
var primaryColorContainer = $(".primary-colors .color");
var primaryValue = $('.primary-range-container .value');

$.fn.colorBlocks(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
    this.change(function() {
        var number = $(rangeSlider).val();
        $(colorContainer).hide();
        $(colorContainer).hide().slice( 0, number ).show();
    }
    this.change();
}

primarySlider.colorBlocks(primaryColorContainer, primaryValue);
```

The expected result in my head would be that the function would work, but so far I'm just not seeing anything and instead the compiler is giving me `Parsing error: Unexpected Token {`.

Any advice or better methods would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: $.fn.colorBlocks(colorContainer, rangeSlider) { what does this do?

Comment: Got your code to work, see my answer below. Also, you need to update value of that number besides slider, I left an id for you just change inner HTML of that element to number ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your syntax.

Where you define your prototype:

```
$.fn.colorBlocks(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
```

**Should be:**

```
$.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
```

And you're missing a closing parenthesis that is opened in the change listener:

```
this.change(function() {
...
};
```

**Should be:**

```
this.change(function() {
...
});
```

The error is coming from the fact that it is reaching the opening curly brace before it is expcted due to the incorrect syntax when defining the prototype.

**Fixed example:**

```js
var primarySlider = $(".primary-slider");
var primaryColorContainer = $(".primary-colors .color");
var primaryValue = $('.primary-range-container .value');

$.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider, primaryValue) {
  this.change(function() {
    var number = $(rangeSlider).val();
    $(primaryValue).text(number);
    $(colorContainer).hide();
    $(colorContainer).hide().slice( 0, number ).show();
  });
  this.change();
}

primarySlider.colorBlocks(primaryColorContainer, primarySlider, primaryValue);
```

```css
div.color {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-colors">
 <h3>Primary Colors</h3>
 <div class="primary-range-container">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value ="5" class="primary-slider">
  <span class="value">5</span>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <div class="color-container">
  <div class="color primary-color-1"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-2"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-3"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-4"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-5"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-6"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-7"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-8"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-9"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-10"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-11"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is where I got with debugging but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is answers the question in regards to the syntax error, I'll see if I can determine what else is wrong with it, that cause it to fail.

Comment: Try the snippet now.  You weren't passing the slider into it as an argument. instead you passing the value (`primaryValue`), where it was expecting the slider (`rangeSlider`). I also fixed to show the correct number of items selected. You had a min of 1, a default of 5, but start out showing 0. And I added a little demo CSS so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this JS

```
    var primarySlider = $(".primary-slider");
    var primaryColorContainer = $(".primary-colors .color");
    var primaryValue = $('.primary-range-container input');
    var primaryValueDisplay = $('.primary-range-container .value');


    $.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
        this.change(function() {
            var number = $(rangeSlider).val();
            $(colorContainer).hide();
            $(colorContainer).hide().slice(0, number).show();
            primaryValueDisplay.html(number)

        })
        this.change();
    }

    primarySlider.colorBlocks(primaryColorContainer, primaryValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found couple other bugs inside: I think this is what you wanted to do:

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/495texs9/)

HTML:

```
<div class="primary-colors">
   <h3>Primary Colors</h3>
   <div class="primary-range-container">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value ="5" class="primary-slider">
    <span id="sliderValue" class="value">0</span>
   </div>

   <div class="color-container">
    <div class="color primary-color-1">1</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-2">2</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-3">3</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-4">4</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-5">5</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-6">6</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-7">7</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-8">8</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-9">9</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-10">10</div>
    <div class="color primary-color-11">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var primarySlider = $(".primary-slider");
var primaryColorContainer = $(".primary-colors .color");
var primaryValue = $('.primary-range-container .value');

$.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
  this.change(function() {
    var number = $(rangeSlider).val();
    //$(colorContainer).hide();
    $(colorContainer).each(function(i1,obj) {
     if(i1 < number){
        $(this).hide();
     }
     else $(this).show();
 });
  });
  this.change();
}

primarySlider.colorBlocks(primaryColorContainer, primarySlider);
```

I left an Id for you to update value of slider (number to the right), and optional hide commented, toggle it back on if you wish

Answer (score 0):

You have syntactical error. function should be defined as
`$.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {`
.

`this.change(function() {
...
});`

```js
var primarySlider = $(".primary-slider");
var primaryColorContainer = $(".primary-colors .color");
var primaryValue = $('.primary-range-container .value');

$.fn.colorBlocks = function(colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
  this.change(function() {
    var number = $(rangeSlider).val();
        $(colorContainer).hide();
        $(colorContainer).hide().slice( 0, number ).show();
   });
  this.change();
}

primarySlider.colorBlocks(primaryColorContainer, primaryValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="primary-colors">
 <h3>Primary Colors</h3>
 <div class="primary-range-container">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="15" value ="5" class="primary-slider">
  <span class="value">0</span>
 </div>
 <hr>
 <div class="color-container">
  <div class="color primary-color-1"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-2"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-3"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-4"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-5"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-6"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-7"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-8"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-9"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-10"></div>
  <div class="color primary-color-11"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

To create a prototype with jQuery you assign to a function

```
$.fn.colorBlocks = function (colorContainer, rangeSlider) {
   //code here
}
```